# How to put variable value in range with hidden rows or in Filter Mode in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code where sometimes I mention the range with multiple areas dynamically or selecting data in filter mode.

The problem occurs when I put the updated value again in the same range.

It only updates first row value in all range cells or do incorrectly.

```
Dim Rng as Range, RngVar
Set Rng = Range("A5:BG20001,A20005:BG30000")
RngVar = Rng.Value
For i = LBound(RngVar) to Ubound(RngVar)
'Some update on each RngVar row
Next i

Rng.Value = RngVar
```

How it should be done without looping every row or efficiently?

Comment: Btw `RngVar` is not what you think it is. It only contains the first area `A5:BG20001`. This is easily verified by `Debug.Print Ubound(rngVar, 1)`, which returns 19997.

Comment: You'd need to loop over the areas in `Range("A5:BG20001,A20005:BG30000")`, read each one to an array, do the update then replace.  Should still be fast...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `RngVar` is not what you think it is. It only contains the `.Value` related to the first area, `A5:BG20001`. You can't read a multi-area Range's `.Value` into an array with a single step like you're attempting.

Loop the `.Areas` and process each individually:

```
Dim Rng as Range, RngVar, Area As Range
Set Rng = Range("A5:BG20001,A20005:BG30000")

For Each Area In Rng.Areas
    RngVar = Area.Value
    For i = LBound(RngVar, 1) To UBound(RngVar, 1)
        'Some update on each RngVar row
    Next
    Area.Value = RngVar
Next
```

Comment: Ok. So I should do Area.Value =RngVar instead Rng.Value =RngVar?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you're writing the array back to the sheet.